# Failed to authorize with google analytics server

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

> I am working on google analytics to show real time visitor information on my website. it is working fine when i login with google accounts in localhost. when i logout google acccount it is failed to authorize. please help.

Comment: Have you tried creating a OAuth2 client ID as presented in https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingoauth2 ?

Comment: yes, i created client id,got the api key and then gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, oauth2callback);

Comment: i am confused why should i login my google account to request analytics data

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/console/help/#WhatIsKey for the difference between Oauth2 Client ID and a API Key. Since you are accessing user data, you need to use a OAuth2 client ID.

Comment: not user data.basically accessing my website's analytics data

Comment: I think this is the definitive link: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication . Not sure if the login page is not being shown -> May be you have disabled popups? What is the exact reason of the failure of authentication?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be looking at Service accounts here.  You only want to show data for your google analytics there is no reason to use the normal oath2 method. With a service account it will only access your account and there will be no need to log in to google.

```
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount
```

Comment: my primary target is.. we have many websites which registered with google analytics. now from another website we want to retrieve analytics data like user visit,new visitor visits and show them. thats all

Comment: If its a site that you have access to.  from your GA account you can use a service account.  If its a Users site that you dont have access to and you want them to be able to see there data on your site. Then you use the normal Oath2 method you are using above.

Comment: from google analytics account we can add website for analytics data which create a profile id. is there any option like service account you told?

Comment: Part of setting up the service account requires you to give it an email address with access. It will then only have access to that single profileId.   https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts

Comment: can you give me an example which use service account credential to retrieve analytics data.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service?hl=fa ..does it have javascript version

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service?hl=fa does it have equivalent in javascript?

Comment: I have looked around i havent been able to find any that use Javascript.  I'm looking into it it might make a good Tutorial.